# ndarray.any() error: ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds

Tags: python, numpy

I run in to the following problem:

Running this code

```
 a = np.array([1,2,3])
 a.any(2)
```

gives me the error: `ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds`

It looks like the method `any()` receives an `axis` argument which is too big. When I try to specify the `axis` argument I receive:

```
a.any(2, axis=1)
--->
TypeError: _any() got multiple values for argument 'axis'
```

Like there was `axis` argument set twice.

I'm using Pyzo2014a ver.3.5 with Python 3.4.3 and numpy 1.10.1

Comment: it's really unclear what you're trying to do here `any` returns `True` if any element is `True` by passing args here you're confusing the params of `axis` and `out`. Are you wanting `(a==2).any()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.any()` tests whether any array element along a given axis evaluates to True. To test if `2` is in `a`, you could use

```
np.any(a==2)
```

or

```
(a==2).any()
```

or just

```
2 in a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 a = np.array([1,2,3])
 a.any(2)
ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds
```

you got this error because you have only one `axis` which is `0` you don't have an axis with the value

the second error

```
a.any(2, axis=1)
--->
TypeError: _any() got multiple values for argument 'axis'
```

because axis is the first `argument` for the method `any` so here you're supplying `2` as the `axis` and again you're assigning `1` to `axis` parameter

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a wrong axis to `any`.Note that the fist argument of `any` is a axis of the array,and since `a` is a one dimensional array you can just pass `0` as it's axis:

```
>>> a.any(0)
True
```

> numpy.any(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False)[source]

If you'd a 2D array you could pass `0` and `1` :

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[0,0,0]])
>>> a.any(0)
array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> a.any(1)
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
(a == 2).any()
```

The method signature for [`any`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) states:

> a : array_like Input array or object that can be converted to an
>   array.
>
> axis : None or int or tuple of ints, optional Axis or axes
>   along which a logical OR reduction is performed. The default (axis =
>   None) is to perform a logical OR over all the dimensions of the input
>   array. axis may be negative, in which case it counts from the last to
>   the first axis. New in version 1.7.0. If this is a tuple of ints, a
>   reduction is performed on multiple axes, instead of a single axis or
>   all the axes as before.
>
> out : ndarray, optional Alternate output array
>   in which to place the result. It must have the same shape as the
>   expected output and its type is preserved (e.g., if it is of type
>   float, then it will remain so, returning 1.0 for True and 0.0 for
>   False, regardless of the type of a). See doc.ufuncs (Section “Output
>   arguments”) for details.
>
> keepdims : bool, optional If this is set to
>   True, the axes which are reduced are left in the result as dimensions
>   with size one. With this option, the result will broadcast correctly
>   against the original arr.

So you're confusing the `axis` param where with the value you're trying to test for hence the errors:

```
In [208]:
a = np.array([1,2,3])
(a==2).any()

Out[208]:
True
```